# Is there a better way of converting Iterator[char] to Seq[String]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Following is my code that I have used to convert Iterator[char] to Seq[String].

```
val result = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream (new File(fileDir)))
val remove_comp = result.grouped(11).map{arr => arr.update(2, 32);arr}.flatMap{arr => arr.update(3, 32); arr}
val convert_iter = remove_comp.map(_.toChar.toString).toSeq.mkString.split("\n")
val rdd_input = Spark.sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(convert_iter)
```

val fileDir:

```
12**34567890
12@@34567890
12!!34567890
12¬¬34567890
12
'34567890
```

I am not happy with this code as the data size is big and converting to string would end up with heap space.

```
val convert_iter = remove_comp.map(_.toChar)
convert_iter: Iterator[Char] = non-empty iterator
```

Is there a better way of coding?

Answer (score 1):

By completely disregarding corner cases about empty Strings etc I would start with something like:

```
val test = Iterable('s','f','\n','s','d','\n','s','v','y')

val (allButOne, last) = test.foldLeft( (Seq.empty[String], Seq.empty[Char]) ) {
  case ((strings, chars), char) =>
    if (char == '\n')
      (strings :+ chars.mkString, Seq.empty)
    else
      (strings, chars :+ char)
}

val result = allButOne :+ last.mkString
```

I am sure it could be made more elegant, and handle corner cases better (once you define you want them handled), but I think it is a nice starting point.

But to be honest I am not entirely sure what you want to achieve. I just guessed that you want to group chars divided by `\n` together and turn them into `String`s.

Comment: First, I wanted to remove 2nd and 3rd bytes. Second, convert the text(new line separated field delimiter) to RDD

Answer (score 0):

*Looking at your code*, I see that you are trying to *replace the special characters* such as `**`, `@@` and so on from the file that contains following data

> `12**34567890
>   12@@34567890
>   12!!34567890
>   12¬¬34567890
>   12
>   '34567890`

For that you can just read the data using *sparkContext textFile* and use regex `replaceAllIn`

```
val pattern = new Regex("[¬~!@#$^%&*\\(\\)_+={}\\[\\]|;:\"'<,>.?` /\\-]")
val result = sc.textFile(fileDir).map(line => pattern.replaceAllIn(line, ""))
```

and you should have you `result` as `RDD[String]` which also an *iterator*

```
1234567890
1234567890
1234567890
1234567890
12
34567890
```

**Updated**

If there are `\n` and `\r` in between the texts *at 3rd and 4th place* and if the *result is all fixed length of 10 digits text* then you can use `wholeTextFiles` api of `sparkContext` and use following *regex* as

```
val pattern = new Regex("[¬~!@#$^%&*\\(\\)_+={}\\[\\]|;:\"'<,>.?` /\\-\r\n]")
val result = sc.wholeTextFiles(fileDir).flatMap(line => pattern.replaceAllIn(line._2, "").grouped(10))
```

You should get the output as

```
1234567890
1234567890
1234567890
1234567890
1234567890
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Regex will not work as the special char can be a new line

Comment: are your lines of fixed length ? as you have used grouped(11) which means that they are of fixed length, isn't it?

Comment: yes, they are fixed length where 2 bytes can be anything

Comment: @Aavik I have updated the answer :) please check now